# Saving the output of multiple files bash

Tags: bash

I have a series of directories, indicated by `species` in the code below. I want to run a series of commands on the files in each directory and then save the output as one file in the corresponding directory. With the following code, I get to only save the output for the last directory. I was wondering how I can solve this problem? Thanks!

```
for dir in ${Addr1}/*/*_files/seq*
do
    species=`echo $dir | cut -f8 -d"/"`
    chr=`echo $dir | cut -f10 -d"/"`
    echo -n -e "${chr} \t"; ./script.py ${Addr1}/${species}/${species}_files/$chr
done > ${Addr1}/${species}/${species}_estimated
```

Comment: The output comes from that last `echo`/`script.py` line? Do the redirection on just that line/those commands then.

Comment: Yes, the output comes from the last line with echo and script.py. Sorry I don't understand the second part of your comment.

Comment: `echo .... >> output_file; ./script.py .... >> output_file` or `{ echo ...; ./script.py; } >> output_file` You are opening the output file *once* **outside** of your loop. You need to open it in the loop for each species.

Comment: Great, I solved it with your comment.

Comment: `IFS=/ read -a fields <<< "$dir"; species=${fields[7]}; chr=${fields[9]}`. This is more efficient than calling `cut` twice.

Answer (score 3):

You have a logic problem:

```
for dir in ${Addr1}/*/*_files/seq*
do
    species=`echo $dir | cut -f8 -d"/"`
    # ...
done > ${Addr1}/${species}/${species}_estimated
```

The problem is that you're assigning a value to `species` only within the loop, yet the output file specified at the end must be opened when the loop begins.

Instead, try this:

```
for dir in ${Addr1}/*/*_files/seq*
do
    species=`echo $dir | cut -f8 -d"/"`
    chr=`echo $dir | cut -f10 -d"/"`
    {
      echo -n -e "${chr} \t";
      ./script.py ${Addr1}/${species}/${species}_files/$chr;
    } >> ${Addr1}/${species}/${species}_estimated
done
```

Now when the output file is opened, the `species` variable is correctly set.  Each output file will be closed and the next one opened during each loop iteration.

Comment: Do you mean it's impossible to have a separate output for each species?

Comment: Oh, your statement about "save the output as one file" confused me.  I've updated my answer to produce multiple output files.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Are you happy now?!  ;-)  But seriously, I had no idea about braces being used in that way until now.  So thanks.